# node.js : How to combine a server that does post requests on a timed basis, with a server which listens for events

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, server, event-handling

So I am working on a project where there is a program like the following:

```
async function watch(){
    "does post requests"
}
async function timer() {
    await watch();
};
let tmr = setInterval(function(){ timer() }, 6 * 1000);

async function main() {
   "does event listening"
}
main()
```

and it is very clunky.

I am wondering if there are any node wizards here that can help with this sort of architecture problem?

I.e. How to combine a server that does post requests on a timed basis, with a server which listens for events.

Comment: I'm confused as to what has you confused.  Just design your web server as you would normally design your web server (to process incoming http requests) and then add to it some timer driven code that makes outbound requests to some other server.  There's no magic here at all.  An http server listening for inbound requests can also have code that makes outbound http requests.  Where are you stuck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might interest you is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

You could simply create the http server and declare routes to receive requests, and configure node cron-job that will send requests of your choice on a timed basis.